# How to make meson scan for new target

Tags: meson-build

I have meson project which have multiple targets in multiple subdirs.
When I add a new target into the project in a subdir, and try to compile that target, an error occurs:

```
ERROR: Can't invoke target `test`: target not found
```

The only way I have to compile the target is to setup again the project

```
meson setup builddir --wipe
```

Is the any command to make the build system scan for changes in subdirs' `meson.build` files?

Comment: meson --reconfigure ./build  or   meson -Dexamples=all --reconfigure ./build

Answer (score 1):

You have two more options after you have changed subfiles:

- run `meson --reconfigure builddir` to force reconfiguration. `setup --wipe` will remove the build directory, in case something corrupted the cache or builddir - and than creates a (new) configuration.
- touch the root's `meson.build` (`touch meson.build`), then when you run `ninja -C builddir` again, it will reconfigure before building automatically since the time stamp of the root's `meson.build` doesn't match with the cache's anymore. The [manual](https://mesonbuild.com/FAQ.html#but-i-really-want-to-use-wildcards) suggests, it's also possible to let the system send signals to a script which touches the main `meson.build` when change events are noticed.